# Negative vphantom

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath

The following minimal code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\mycircb[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=-1.5pt]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.8pt, scale=0.8] 
  {\upshape \footnotesize \textbf{#1}};\!\!
}
\newcommand*\Swtch[3]{%
    \xrightarrow[{\text{\mycircb{#2} $>$ \mycircb{#3}}}]{\text{#1}} 
}

\begin{document}
\[
\Swtch{Boo}{A}{B}
\]
\end{document}
```

produces the following picture

[image: Picture]

There is a little bit too much vertical spacing below the arrow. How do I make the 'denominator' move closer to the dividing arrow? I'm looking for something like a negative \vphantom command. Similarly, suppose I wanted to adjust the 'numerator' spacing. Space can be added by using \vphantom, but how can space be *removed*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\newcommand*{\Swtch}[3]{%
  \mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip%
  \hbox{\phantom{\,\mycircb{#2}}{\scriptsize#1}}\vskip-0.4ex\hbox{\ensuremath{\xrightarrow[\hphantom{\text{\mycircb{#2} $>$ \mycircb{#3}}}]{}}}\vskip-1.8ex\hbox{\,\text{\mycircb{#2} $>$ \mycircb{#3}}}}}%
}
```

The first `\phantom` and the two uses of `\,` is a bit of a hack used to center the text, but should be what you are looking for. You can adjust the amount of space by changing the parameters to the two `\vskip`.

Here is the comparison:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I simple `\vskip` or `\vspace` with a negative (or positive) value should be used for such cases. I have the feeling that the OP only knows about `\vphantom`.

Comment: Complicated, but interesting. I decided to accept this answer, as it seems the most flexible (as opposed to the \smash command). Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `\vphantom` you could use `\settoheight{\yourlengthcmd}{text}` to get the height of the argument and apply this as negative space.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\smash`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\mycircb[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=-1.5pt]\node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.8pt, scale=0.8]
  {\upshape \footnotesize \textbf{#1}};\!\!
}
\newcommand*\Swtch[3]{%
    \xrightarrow[{\text{\mycircb{#2} $>$ \mycircb{#3}}}]{\text{#1}}
}

\newcommand*\Swtchnew[3]{%
    \xrightarrow[\smash{\text{\mycircb{#2} $>$ \mycircb{#3}}}]{\text{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\Swtch{Boo}{A}{B}  \Swtchnew{Boo}{A}{B}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: \xarrowright with \smash]