# \widetilde with Type 1 font

Tags: positioning, accents

I am trying to use `\widetilde` with a custom font called LTL fonts http://theory.stanford.edu/~matteo/ltlfonts/

From its description:

> The font is distributed in outline Type 1 format, with associated TeX (TFM), Adobe (AFM), and Microsoft (PFM) font metrics.

The thing is when I use `\widetilde{\LTLcircle}`, it appears like

[image: the tilde is too low]

Apparently the tilde is too close to the circle, and I would like to raise it a bit.

I found a [related question about how to lower the tilde](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/how-do-i-lower-the-widetilde-accent-i-e-move-it-closer-to-the-variable),
unfortunately I can't find the way to "raise" it.

Comment: You could lower the `\LTLcircle` with for example `$\widetilde{\raisebox{-2pt}{\LTLcircle}}$`, but I am not sure whether it would be satisfactory.

Comment: Wondering if [this question on a similar issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24850/negative-vphantom/24859#24859) helps. Also, please add a link to the question about how to lower the tilde.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to [this quesion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/how-do-i-lower-the-widetilde-accent-i-e-move-it-closer-to-the-variable), in which case try that solution but change the -ve values to positive to move it up

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to lower the object over which the `\widetilde` spans - "O" in this case. To achieve this, use

```
$\widetilde{\raisebox{-4pt}{$O$}}$ "raises" O by -4pt
```

However, this causes the entire structure to drop 4pt below the baseline. To correct for this, raise the entire structure (including the `\widetilde`) the same amount as what you dropped it.

```
...
\usepackage{graphicx}% Contains the \raisebox{...}{...} command
\newcommand*{\wtilde}[2][0pt]{% Raised \widetilde: \wtilde[<raise>]{<symbol>}
  \raisebox{#1}{$\widetilde{\raisebox{-#1}{$#2$}}$}%
}%
...
This is a test~$\widetilde{O}$, and another test~$\wtilde{O}$, and yet another~$\wtilde[4pt]{O}$.
```

[image: Raising \widetilde]

The above was not tested using your custom LTL fonts, but in principle it should work regardless of the font selection.

Comment: Thank you too Harrold and Peter, for somewhat reason I can't comment on my question..